# Chosen plugin: Change the background of options depending on its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the simple example's sake: I'd like to change the background color of every option in the dropdown list. Every option should have a background color corresponding to its value.

E.g.

```
$('...').css('background', 'red')
```

I've tried to select .active-result, but it just won't work.

Any ideas?

```
$(function() {

  var $select = $(document.getElementById('foo')),
      colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'silver']
  ;

  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $select[0].add(new Option('Color: ' + colors[i], colors[i]));
  }

  $select[0].options[2].selected = true;

  $select.chosen();

});
```

[Link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/otASETo/1/)

Comment: Why are you doing `$(document.getElementById('foo'))`?!  Where did you learn that?  You have jQuery, use it: `$('#foo')`.

Comment: `$select[0]` will get a DOM element.  Why are you doing that?  Again, you have jQuery, use it: `$select.append(...);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to set the color of the elements?  Try doing it as you are creating them and adding them to the `<select>`.

Also, you have jQuery, use it!  Don't use a mis-mash of jQuery and native DOM methods.

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $('#foo'), // Don't use getElementById
        colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'silver'];

    for(var i = 0, len = colors.length; i < len; i++){ // Don't hard-code the length
        var $option = $('<option></option>', {  // jQuery can create elements
            text: 'Color: ' + colors[i],
            value: colors[i]
        }).css('background-color', colors[i]); // set the color

        $select.append($option); // Append the element using jQuery
    }

    $select.val(colors[2]); // jQuery can also set the "selected" option

    $select.chosen();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/otASETo/3

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to hurt your jQuery feelings. :) I've just done so much jQuery, I thought I'd try to learn some native js as well, and just use jQuery for lame stuff like multiple css properties.

I didn't think Chosen would copy every attribute from the original element, but that was the case and I should of tried it. Instead I tried to apply the styles directly to the chosen generated elements without any luck... Thank you for your help!

Comment: @estrar: You're welcome, glad I could help.  I didn't know the plugin would copy the styles, I just tried it to see what would happen. :-) Yes, I agree you should know how to use native DOM methods, but in this case, let's keep it simple.  It's confusing to read code with mixed styles.